# AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported

Tags: django, django-templates

When i open to click cms-pages , showing error..

```
File "/home2/devnocco/virtual/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/home2/devnocco/virtual/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 307, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home2/devnocco/virtual/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home2/devnocco/virtual/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 79, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home2/devnocco/virtual/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 197, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home2/devnocco/virtual/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_cms-2.2-py2.6.egg/cms/admin/pageadmin.py", line 657, in changelist_view
    cl.set_items(request)

  File "/home2/devnocco/virtual/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_cms-2.2-py2.6.egg/cms/admin/change_list.py", line 198, in set_items
    children[-1].last = False

  File "/home2/devnocco/virtual/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 157, in __getitem__
    "Negative indexing is not supported."

AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported.
```

Comment: Please provide more context. "When i open to click cms-pages"? What projects are you using, what URL are you loading?

Answer (score 3):

This will happen mostly when you are trying some indexing related operation on an empty list. Try this instead:

```
somelist=[]
last_element = somelist[len(somelist)-1]
```

Comment: little typo I guess`last_element = somelist[len(last_element)-1]` should be `last_element = somelist[len(somelist)-1]`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are coming across [this issue](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1099) in django-cms. It's been fixed now, so you could upgrade to the latest release, or manually apply the patch.

You might have to upgrade django-mptt to 0.5.2 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a negative reference just reverse the list such that the last item becomes the first and then use a positive index to access it just like as shown below. I hope this was helpful

```
last_response = Model.objects.filter(author=request.user).order_by("-id")[0].message
```